# JSP Eclipse Dynamic Web project: Javascript file doesn't contain Javascript code, but code from one of JSP pages

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp, tomcat7

I have a dynamic web project in Eclipse, which uses JSP pages. Now, I want to simply upload a regular javascript file with the project. What happens is that instead of javascript code, when I check in console/network (or console/sources), I get code from one of JSP pages in my Javascript file. The name of the file is OK in the browser, it's called javaskriptGlavni.js. 
Picture of console:

[image: js file content]

This my folder structure:

```
WebContent
-css
-META-INF
-resources
 -js
  -javaskriptGlavni.js
WEB-INF
```

This is how I include JS and CSS files

```
<link href="/Projektni2019Glavna/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css" />
<script src="/Projektni2019Glavna/resources/js/javaskriptGlavni.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

CSS file loads well, yet with JS file there is aforementioned issue.

I did look into Tomcat's "wtpwebapps" directory, and it looks fine, it's really a JS file with JS content there:

[image: Tomcat webapp folder structure]

- Tried to clean/rebuild
- Tried to restart server
- Tried to remove project from server, and then add it back
- Tried to change folder structure

Nothing helped. Really couldn't find anything similar on Stack Overflow or rest of the internet.

Comment: You've left some details out. Have you looked at the *contents* of the file on disk? Into what file did you include the JS and CSS files? Which JSP file's contents are you seeing instead of the JS file contents in your browser? What's in your web.xml file for that JSP file?

Comment: @nitind Thanks for your advice, it guided me to discovery of a web.xml issue. I created a response to the question, to explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint, @nitind! It turns out it was web.xml problem.

This is old web.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">   
  <display-name>Projektni2019Glavna</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Controller</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Controller</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.gishas.controller.Controller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now, when I add

```
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

everything is fine, JS file is served with JS code, JS functions are being called from the interface.

I am fairly new with JSP so I am not even sure how this mapping works, and I just copied and adjusted web.xml file from my school example, so I didn't really know Javascript has to be handled this way.